# How to query data in a specific location in MongoDB

Tags: node.js

I am migrating data from another DB to MongoDB.

There is not enough time to change the structure of all DBs, so we are looking for a way to use the data as it is.

'TEST' Collection exists in the DB and contains the data below.

This.db.collection('TEST').findOne() method is used to get the entire data.

I am wondering how to get a specific part of the 'TEST' Collection.

Is there a way to get TEST/FRUIT or TEST/FRUIT/APPLE data?

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a26e198a8dedcfdfa5cbf6"
  },
  "FRUIT": {
    "APPLE": {
      "PRICE": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
      },
      "SUGAR_CONTENT": {
        "$numberInt": "2"
      }
    },
    "MELON": {
      "PRICE": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
      },
      "SUGAR_CONTENT": {
        "$numberInt": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how i tried

```
this.db.collection('TEST').aggregate([{
                    $match : {
                        'parent': 'FRUIT'
                    }
                }
            ]);

            console.log(result);
            for await (var doc of result) {
                // Not Entered
                console.log('res  = %s', doc);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the data for TEST/FRUIT or TEST/FRUIT/APPLE, you can use the dot notation to access the subfields. For example:

```
let cursor = this.db
  .collection("TEST")
  .find({ "FRUIT.APPLE": { $exists: true } });
cursor.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.FRUIT.APPLE);
});
```

or you can use aggregate to get the data.

For example:

```
let cursor = this.db
  .collection("TEST")
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { "FRUIT.APPLE": { $exists: true } } },
    { $project: { "FRUIT.APPLE": 1 } },
  ]);
cursor.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.FRUIT.APPLE);
});
```

Comment: This answer works for me.
However, if the desired data position is passed as a parameter, why doesn't it work?

// Not working
const param = "FRUIT.APPLE";
$match: { param : { $exists: true } }

Comment: I'm glad that the answer worked for you. When you write param: { $exists: true }, MongoDB interprets it literally and looks for a field named "param" in the documents, not the value of the variable param.